# What is the meaning of 'config = wandb.config'?

Tags: python, wandb

I try to do the settings for a sweep for my Logistic regression model. I read the tutorials of wandb and cannot understand how to make the configurations and especially the meaning of `config=wandb.config` in the tutorials. I would really appreciate it if someone gave me a good explanation of the steps. Here is what I've done:

```
sweep_config = {
    'method': 'grid'
}

metric = {
    'name': 'f1-score',
    'goal': 'maximize'
}

sweep_config['metric'] = metric

parameters = {
    'penalty': {
        'values': ['l2']
    },
    'C': {
        'values': [0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0, 100.0]
    }
}

sweep_config['parameters'] = parameters
```

Then I create the yaml file:

```
stream = open('config.yaml', 'w')
yaml.dump(sweep_config, stream)
```

Then it's time for training:

```
with wandb.init(project=WANDB_PROJECT_NAME):
    config = wandb.config
    
    features = pd.read_csv('data/x_features.csv')
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2))

    X_features = features = vectorizer.fit_transform(features['lemmatized_reason'])

    y_labels = pd.read_csv('data/y_labels.csv')

    split_data = train_test_split(X_features, y_labels, train_size = 0.85, test_size = 0.15, stratify=y_labels)
    features_train, labels_train = split_data[0], split_data[2]
    features_test, labels_test = split_data[1], split_data[3]
    
    config = wandb.config
    log_reg = LogisticRegression(
        penalty=config.penalty,
        C = config.C
    )
    
    log_reg.fit(features_train, labels_train)
    
    labels_pred = log_reg.predict(features_test)
    labels_proba = log_reg.predict_proba(features_test)
    labels=list(map(str,y_labels['label'].unique()))
    
    # Visualize single plot
    cm = wandb.sklearn.plot_confusion_matrix(labels_test, labels_pred, labels)
    
    score_f1 = f1_score(labels_test, labels_pred, average='weighted')
    
    sm = wandb.sklearn.plot_summary_metrics(
    log_reg, features_train, labels_train, features_test, labels_test)
    
    roc = wandb.sklearn.plot_roc(labels_test, labels_proba)
    
    wandb.log({
        "f1-weighted-log-regression-tfidf-skf": score_f1, 
        "roc-log-regression-tfidf-skf": roc, 
        "conf-mat-logistic-regression-tfidf-skf": cm,
        "summary-metrics-logistic-regression-tfidf-skf": sm
        })
```

And finally sweep_id and agent outside of `with` statement:

```
sweep_id = wandb.sweep(sweep_config, project="multiple-classifiers")
wandb.agent(sweep_id)
```

There is something major I am missing here with this config thing, that I just cannot understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at Weights & Biases. With wandb Sweeps, the idea is that wandb needs to be able to change the hyperparameters in the sweep.

The below section where the hyperparameters are passed to `LogisticRegression` could also be re-written

```
config = wandb.config
log_reg = LogisticRegression(
    penalty=config.penalty,
    C = config.C
)
```

like this:

```
log_reg = LogisticRegression(
    penalty=wandb.config.penalty,
    C = wandb.config.C
)
```

However, I think you're missing defining a train function or train script, which needs to also be passed to wandb. With out it, your example above won't work.

Below is a minimal example that should help. Hopefully the [sweeps documentation](https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/sweeps) can also help.

```
import numpy as np 
import random
import wandb

#  Step 1: Define sweep config
sweep_configuration = {
    'method': 'random',
    'name': 'sweep',
    'metric': {'goal': 'maximize', 'name': 'val_acc'},
    'parameters': 
    {
        'batch_size': {'values': [16, 32, 64]},
        'epochs': {'values': [5, 10, 15]},
        'lr': {'max': 0.1, 'min': 0.0001}
     }
}

#  Step 2: Initialize sweep by passing in config
sweep_id = wandb.sweep(sweep_configuration)

def train_one_epoch(epoch, lr, bs): 
  acc = 0.25 + ((epoch/30) +  (random.random()/10))
  loss = 0.2 + (1 - ((epoch-1)/10 +  random.random()/5))
  return acc, loss

def evaluate_one_epoch(epoch): 
  acc = 0.1 + ((epoch/20) +  (random.random()/10))
  loss = 0.25 + (1 - ((epoch-1)/10 +  random.random()/6))
  return acc, loss

def train():
    run = wandb.init()

    #  Step 3: Use hyperparameter values from `wandb.config`
    lr  =  wandb.config.lr
    bs = wandb.config.batch_size
    epochs = wandb.config.epochs

    for epoch in np.arange(1, epochs):
      train_acc, train_loss = train_one_epoch(epoch, lr, bs)
      val_acc, val_loss = evaluate_one_epoch(epoch)

      wandb.log({
        'epoch': epoch, 
        'train_acc': train_acc,
        'train_loss': train_loss, 
        'val_acc': val_acc, 
        'val_loss': val_loss
      })

#  Step 4: Launch sweep by making a call to `wandb.agent`
wandb.agent(sweep_id, function=train, count=4)
```

Finally, can you share the link where you found the code above? Maybe we need to update some examples :)

Comment: Is creating train function mandatory? Also in sweeps walkthrough there are two lines of code that I don't understand. The first is the one I mention in my question. The other one is `hyperparameters = config.config`. How is this python file supposed to be structured?

Comment: Yep you need to pass either a function or .py file to the sweep, so that it can then run training on 1 or more of your machines. 

Could you share the link to the walkthrough you are looking at? Maybe we can make it clearer.

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/github/wandb/examples/blob/master/colabs/pytorch/Organizing_Hyperparameter_Sweeps_in_PyTorch_with_W%26B.ipynb - this is it.